# Ways for reading inputs in C without reading newline or using scanf

Tags: c, string, input, integer

I have a college exercise to do, that consists in writing a bank in C and I do know that `scanf` is a really buggy function and `fgets` reads the `'\n'`, that I don't really want to be read. So I have written new functions trying to solve this problem:

```
char *readstr(char *buff, size_t bytes) {
    char *ptr;
    for (ptr = buff;
         (*ptr = getchar()) != '\n' && *ptr != EOF && ptr - buff < bytes - 1;
         ptr++)
        ;
    int c = *ptr;
    *ptr = '\0';
    if (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ;
    }
    return buff;
}

int readint() {
    char buffer[256] = "";
    readstr(buffer, 256);
    return atoi(strpbrk(buffer, "0123456789"));
}

double readfloat() {
  char buffer[256] = "";
  readstr(buffer, 256);
  return atof(strpbrk(buffer, "0123456789"));
}

char readchar() {
  char buffer[2] = "";
  readstr(buffer, 2);
  return *buffer;
}
```

until now, I wrote these ones. Any advice or suggestion? a more elegant one or simpler solution? apparently they work, but I don't know if this is the best approach.

Comment: Why don't you want to read the newline? If you don't need it, just remove it from the buffer after you read it.

Comment: The `scanf()` function is rarely buggy, but it _is_ hard (really quite hard) to use correctly.  Something is going to have to read the newline — you won't get far without reading it at some point.

Comment: `scanf` is not buggy. The “problem” with it is novice programmers use it incorrectly. The new-line character is in the input stream, so it must be read. Removing it from the data returned by `fgets` is trivial: If the last character is a new-line character, replace it with a null character.

Comment: In your `readstr`, `*ptr = getchar()` is wrong because `*ptr` is a `char` and `getchar` returns an `int`, notably including the `EOF` value, which typically is not representable in a `char`. So the assignment loses the value.

Answer (score 1):

scanf is not buggy, it's simply hard to use correctly.

Anyway, you can use fgets and remove manually the newline character. A way to do this is by using the [`strcspn`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) function like follows:

```c
fgets(str, size, stdin);
str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;
```

Comment: While this is a very simple solution, note that it wont read the same number of characters as the OP's function because `fgets()` needs an extra element for the newline. The OP also wants to discard the extra bytes on the line.

Answer (score 1):

Your goal seems to read a line of input into a buffer with a given size, not storing the trailing newline and discarding any excess characters present on the line. You do need to *read* the newline so it does not linger in the input stream, but you do not want to store it into the destination array as `fgets()` does.

Note that this can be achieved with `scanf()` this way:'

```
char buf[100] = "";
if (scanf("%99[^\n]", buf) == EOF) {
    // handle end of file
} else {
    // line was read into buf or empty line was detected and buf was not modified
    scanf("%*[^\n]");  // consume extra bytes on the line if any
    scanf("%*1[\n]");  // consume the newline if present
}
```

This is very cumbersome, and it gets even worse if the buffer size is a variable value. As many savvy C programmers noted, `scanf` is not *buggy*, it is just difficult to use correctly. I would even say its semantics are confusing and error prone, yet it can be used safely, unlike `gets()`, which was removed from recent versions of the C Standard because any arbitrary long input can cause undefined behavior with it.

Reading a line and discarding the trailing newline can be done with `fgets()`, but combining the reading the line, discarding extra bytes and consuming the newline may be useful as a separate function.

There are problems in your code:

- you store the return value of `getchar()` directly into the `char` array, removing the distinction between `EOF` and the char value `'\377'` on architectures with signed chars, while `*ptr != EOF` would never match on architectures where `char` is unsigned by default. You must store it into an `int` variable.
- there is no way to tell if the end of file was reached: the function returns an empty string at end of file, just like it does for blank lines int the stream
- the buffer size cannot be zero.
- truncation cannot be detected: instead of returning the destination array, you could return the number of characters needed for the full line and -1 at end of file.
- calling `atoi(strpbrk(buffer, "0123456789"))` poses multiple problems: `strpbrk` can return a null pointer, causing undefined behavior, it will skip a leading sign, and `atoi` is not fully defined for contents representing values out of range for type `int`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readstr(char *buff, size_t bytes) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n') {
        if (pos + 1 < bytes)
            buff[pos] = (char)c;
        pos++;
    }
    if (size > 0) {
        if (pos < size)
            buff[pos] = '\0';
        else
            buff[size - 1] = '\0';
    }
    if (c == EOF && pos == 0)
        return -1;
    return (int)pos;
}

int readint(void) {
    char buffer[256];
    long n;
    if (readstr(buffer, sizeof buffer) < 0)
        return -1;
    n = strtol(buffer, NULL, 0);
#if LONG_MIN < INT_MIN
    if (n < INT_MIN) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return INT_MIN;
    }
#endif
#if LONG_MAX > INT_MAX
    if (n > INT_MAX) {
        errno = ERANGE;
        return INT_MAX;
    }
#endif
    return (int)n;
}

double readdouble(void) {
    char buffer[256];
    if (readstr(buffer, sizeof buffer) < 0)
        return NAN;
    else
        return strtod(buffer, NULL);
}

int readchar(void) {
    char buffer[2] = "";
    if (readstr(buffer, sizeof buffer) < 0)
        return EOF;
    else
        return (unsigned char)*buffer;
}
```